# Alguém pode me explicar este erro?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho 2 tabelas, produtos e fornecedores. E está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Produtos_Fornecedor". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\TIAGO\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\PROJETOS\TRABALHO FINAL POO\TRABALHO FINAL POO\BD.MDF", table "dbo.Fornecedor", column 'cnpj'.

Alguém pode me explicar este erro?

Comment: A mensagem está informando qual o erro: Você está tentando inserir um produto cujo dado que é chave do fonecedor (`cnpj`) não é válido - Ou seja, não existe um fornecedor cadastrado com o cnpj informado

Comment: Se ainda assim, ficou alguma dúvida, inclua o seu código à pergunta

Answer (score 2):

O erro é bem claro, conflito de chave estrangeira... Você está tentando inserir na tabela `[Produtos]` um produto com um Fornecedor que não existe, no caso na coluna CNPJ, que parece ser a sua fk

Answer (score 1):

Faça o insert na tabela [Fornecedores] antes de fazer o insert na tabela [Produtos]. Com isso, o banco de dados vai conseguir localizar o registro do fornecedor que você está tentando referenciar nesse insert que está apresentando erro.

Comment: Não consigo, está acusando erro na sintaxe e o comando ta assim:
string insere = "INSERT INTO " + table + "  VALUES (" + y.txt1cadforn.Text + ",'" + y.txt2cadforn.Text.ToString() + "','" + y.txt3cadforn.Text.ToString() + "','" + y.txt4cadforn.Text.ToString() + "');";

Tem algum erro?

Comment: Provavelmente o erro de sintaxe é por conta das aspas. Tente o seguinte:

`"INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES ('" + y.txt1cadforn.Text + "','" + y.txt2cadforn.Text.ToString() + "','" + y.txt3cadforn.Text.ToString() + "','" + y.txt4cadforn.Text.ToString() + "');";`

No entanto, verificando esse trecho de seu código imagino que esteja concatenando o resultado dos campos do formulário diretamente para executar no banco de dados, isso pode te causar problemas sérios de segurança se não for uma aplicação de testes.